# Matching enum value in switch when enum implements a protocol

Tags: swift, switch-statement

I've got a protocol

```
protocol P { }
```

and it's implemented by an enum

```
enum E: P {
    case a
    case b
}
```

So far, so good.

I want to be able to receive instances of `P`, and return a specific value if it's one of `E` (there will be other enums / structs etc implementing P in the future).

I've tried this:

```
extension P {

    var value: String {
        switch self {
            case E.a: return "This is an E.a"
            default: return "meh"
        }
    }
}
```

But this doesn't compile

```
error: Temp.playground:14:16: error: enum case 'a' is not a member of type 'Self'
    case E.a: return "hello"
```

I've also tried:

```
 case is E.a: return "This is an E.a"
```

which just gives this error:

```
 error: Temp.playground:14:19: error: enum element 'a' is not a member type of 'E'
     case is E.a: return "hello"
             ~ ^
```

I know I could do it like this:

```
switch self {
    case let e as E:
        switch e {
            case E.a: return "hello"
            default: return "meh"
        }
    default: return "meh"
}
```

but I really really don't want to!

Is there a syntax or technique I'm missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to match against type `E` before you can test against the
value `E.a`, but this can be done in a single expression:

```
extension P {    
    var value: String? {
        switch self {
        case let e as E where e == .a:
            return "hello"
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't think that `where e == .a` would compile - I would have assumed that `E` would have to implement equatable. I should have tried it. In hindsight, that's done for me by the compiler. Thanks!

Comment: One question. How `P` knows that somewhere `enum` is using him ?

Comment: @Martin sir  it that indicates if something `enum\struct \class` implements  any protocol `P` then that  `enum\struct \class`  = `P`.self , i am very thankful if you explain a little thing

Comment: Hmmm, I thought Swift could do the type casting implicitly (indeed it can if you do `switch self as Any { case E.a: ...`). Will do some digging...

Comment: @Hamish: You are right, that works as well. I didn't think of that.

Comment: Ah, the problem is when switching over a generic-typed value, e.g `func foo<T>(_ t: T) -> String { switch t { case E.a: ...` also fails (an instance member in a protocol extension has an implicit `<Self : P>` placeholder that `self` is typed as). So `switch self as P` also works. Not sure if an oversight or intentional (the logic [just isn't implemented](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/5f595ac4307f9207159008aa664caa56f79e263c/lib/Sema/TypeCheckPattern.cpp#L1417)); I'll file a bug regardless.

Comment: Bug filed: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-6955 (I'll try and fix it myself if I get some time)

Comment: Note that you could also say `case E.a as E` :)

Answer (score 1):

You can define your `P` extension with specific type `enum` in your case

create extension like this

```
extension P where Self == E {
    var value:String {
        switch self  {
        case .a  :
                return "A"
        case .b:
            return "b"

        }
    }
}

let e = E.a.value
print(e)
```

Output :

> "A"

Comment: That's nice, but (and I didn't make this clear in the question, sorry) I don't know that I actually have an `E` when I call `p.value` - it's in a method like `func f(p: P) { p.value }` so the compiler won't like this :|

Answer (score 0):

You are using it wrongly: If you extend `P`, you can only access members of `P`, not of `E`.

I wouldn't recomment extending `P` and adding all the `E` stuff in there, using casting, but rather extend `E` like this:

```
protocol P { 
    var value:String { get }
}

// Default implementation
extension P  {
    var value: String { return ""  }
}

enum E: P {
    case a
    case b
}

extension E {

    var value: String {
        switch self {
            case .a: return "This is an E.a"
            default: return "meh"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But then I can't call `value` - the place where I need to use is is given a `P`, not an `E` :| I would have assumed that because E implements P{ the compiler would have accepted that the switch could match on members of `E` :(

Comment: I just modified the code; the solution is to have a property getter declared in the protocol

Comment: Hmmm, after your edit, all implementations of `P` would require a `value`, which isn't quite what I want (my use case has `value` file private in a different swift file and not public). It's better than anything I've come up with yet though!

Comment: You could provide a default implementation for `P`, see my edit.

Comment: It's more that the `value` method is very specific to a single file/use-case and I wouldn't want it to be public on the protocol.